# Handle no internet connection errors with Combine and URLSession

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to wrap all errors into one class, with Combine and URLSession. However, I can't map the "No internet connection" errors.

This is my code:

```
func request<T>(type: T.Type, urlRequest: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Resource<Response<T>>, Error> where T : GenericDecodable {
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .tryMap({ try NetworkController.handleURLResponse(output: $0, url: urlRequest) })
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

static func handleURLResponse<T>(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, url: URLRequest) throws -> Resource<Response<T>> {
    guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkingError.badURLResponse(url: url) }
    
    var finalResponse: Response<T>
    do {
        finalResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<T>.self, from: output.data)
    } catch {
        return Resource.networkError(data: nil)
    }
    
    switch response.statusCode {
        case 200..<300:
            return Resource.success(data: finalResponse)
        case 422, 400:
            return Resource.validationError(data: finalResponse)
        default:
            return Resource.networkError(data: nil)
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the server sends malformed JSON or something like that, my code works without any problem. But if I disable the internet connection on my phone, I mean if there is no response from the server, my tryMap method is not calling. I only see some text of logs. Like these:

```
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://api-panel-gw.productplus.conf/api/customers/login?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api-panel-gw.productplus.conf/api/customers/login?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

If this happens, I want to send `Resource.networkError(data: nil)` to the subscriber.

I tried to put .mapError above the .tryMap, but no luck. I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "If this happens, I want to send Resource.networkError(data: nil) to the subscriber" That's exactly what you _are_ doing. You are passing `Resource.networkError(data: nil)` down the pipeline as the value (output).

Comment: No, my sink method is not calling when an internet connection error occurs.

Comment: There is no sink method in the code you have shown, so I can't comment. Do you mean the sink is never reached at all? Show your code and explain what you mean the issue is.

Comment: Also please fill in the missing info. What's a Resource?

Comment: You got me wrong. In my sink method, receiveCompletion is called with the error. But I want to replace it with my Resource.networkError method like I do in the tryMap for successful requests. After the replacement, I want to send this value to my subscriber's receiveValue method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mapError` in your sample code is not currently returning anything (it's returning type `Void` or `()`).  It currently just prints something.  The publisher it creates is expected to return some kind of `Error`.  The compiler is complaining because the return type of your block does not match what it expects.  You should return some kind of Error from the `mapError` block.

```
enum MyNetworkErrors : Error {
    case networkUnavailable(String)
}


func doDownload() {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://somedomain.com/path")!)
        .mapError {
            (networkError : URLError) -> Error  in

            /* Note that all the return paths in this block return some kind of Error */

            if nil != networkError.networkUnavailableReason {
                return MyNetworkErrors.networkUnavailable(networkError.localizedDescription)
            }

            return networkError
        }
    /* Other modifiers here */
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: OK.  I did.  `mapError` accepts one kind of error and has to return a different error.  It can be the same type, or a different type, but it has to conform to the `Error` protocol.